# Can I find which script outputs which error?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

There is a script which calls other scripts and they call others... I don't know exactly which scripts are called and how many of them. I only know that some of them are adding iptables rules and I get this error when I call root script.

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

My problem is that I can not find which script outputs this errors. Is there any way or tool to learn that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trace the execution of a series of scripts using `bash -x`

```
bash -x /path/to/your/script
```

From this you can figure out which scripts are being called. You can force the script to abort early using the `-e` switch

```
bash -e -x /path/to/your/script
```

which may save you having to wade through lots of output

Answer (score 1):

You can simply redirect stdout and sterr of the executed script to a file. Each script output can be directed to a separate file. In this case, you can look at these files and check which script returned an error.

To redirect output, you can use:

```
/path/to/script > /path/to/logfile.log
```

To redirect stdout and stderr, you can use:

```
/path/to/script > /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1
```

You can replace `>` with `>>` to append to the file instead of truncating it each time.

Comment: The OP has already stated "I don't know exactly which scripts are called and how many of them".

Comment: Even though, getting output from these scripts will be useful.

Comment: That's perfectly true and in most cases is exactly what I would do. However, in *this* instance, redirecting each script to a separate file cannot be done because the scripts are unknown.